# How does a very bright but very small source of light look like?

Tags: visible-light

How does a very bright but very small source of light look like?
If its smaller than resolving power of eye but (very very bright and far star) brighter than sun?

Comment: Google "point source."

Answer (score 0):

If the source is a star brighter than the sun but to far away for our eyes to resolve then a telescope will improve the situation. In other words its no different than any source but because of the inverse square law by the time the light reaches us the number of photons are very small.

Comment: The star is so bright that while seen from earth is brighter than sun